# How to manage ranking system in Solr

Tags: solr

I have a Solr setup to implement a search engine.

The search engine works (should work) using ranking.

At the same time I'd like to show regular purchased low rank products on top of the results.

Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: What do you want to use for ranking? Do you have a field in your index you want to sort by, or do you want to apply some other algorithm? What is this ranking based on?

Answer (score 1):

Solr is built on top of [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org), and what we call *ranking* is known as *[scoring](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#scoring)* in the Lucene/Solr universe.

This "relevancy score" is computed based on several things that obviously depends on the index and the query, but the *scoring formula* is called [Similarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html) :

> Generally, the Query determines which documents match (a binary
>   decision), while the Similarity determines how to assign scores to the
>   matching documents.

- Index : Scoring is very much dependent on the way documents are indexed (fieldType definition, norms, etc. and also index time boost will affect scoring at query time).
- Query : Lucene usually finds the documents that need to be scored based on boolean logic in the query specification, and then *ranks* this subset of matching documents via a [retrieval model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Model_types) (similarity).
- Similarity : This is how Lucene actually determines how to weight the matched terms.

In general, one doesn't have to tweak Similarity unless having very specific and precise needs. When the matching works but not the scoring, in most of the cases re-ranking the result set by adjusting query parameters is sufficient (e.g. boost queries & functions, sorting, grouping).

Now in order to show *additional products* on top of some results, you can use the [Query Elevation Component](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/the-query-elevation-component.html) :

> The Query Elevation Component lets you configure the top results for a given query regardless of the normal Lucene scoring.

It is very useful in situations where you want to arbitrarily promote some contents regardless of the user query, because such query might not necessarily match the contents to promote, in which case it would not be possible to boost them to the top without OR-ing the main query in the first place.

Read also [Solr Relevancy FAQ](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ).